# Nine patch does not respect content area

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a 9 patch background around an image to add a shadow around it.

What I have done so far is the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/film_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/movie_shadow"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="auto" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_avatar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/film_test" >

    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Whit the following "movie_shadow.9.png":

[image: 9 patch image used as background]

I defined the content area (right and bottom edge) to be the white rectangle.

But the result is not what I expect. The content area is not what I define and the ImaveView is larger than the content area set in the 9 patch.

[image]

You see the red circle on the screenshot?
Why does the ImageView do not respect the content area of 9.png image?

Comment: Adjust the ImageView's margins. Also, assign the 9 patch to the ImageView and get rid of the useless container.

Comment: I will try for the margins, but I don't understand why I should add them. For the useless container, I tried without it at first but the image stop being rendered in eclipse as soon as I add the `android:background` property.

Comment: The margins are needed to fit the image dimensions to the 9 patch. Even though I think you'll need to play a bit before finding the perfect match. Then repeat the process for all the supported resolutions and provide different margin sizes in your dimens files.